# How to show HTML buttons on the top of publisher video in the opentok Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, opentok, tokbox

I am building video conferencing application in Cordova. And for this I am using Opentok plugin from here.
https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok

And for sample apps I am using this repo. https://github.com/opentok/opentok-cordova-samples

I am doing following code to show my buttons on the top of publisher video

```
document.getElementById('publisher').style.zIndex = 'display: none !important;';
OT.updateViews();
```

But in this case publisher video is hidden. Could you please anyone help me to show buttons on the top of publisher video. and both video and buttons are visible to user.